# Restoring force in a crystal

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, crystals

Consider a simple, cubic crystal, such as NaCl. Imagine displacing slightly one Na+ ion in any direction, then releasing it. The ion will quickly return to its equilibrium position. What is the restoring force? From Gauss's law, there is no net electrostatic force from all the other ions. Presumably, the force is quantum mechanical in origin. Is there a simple way to describe it?

Comment: [The stability of matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_of_matter).

Comment: How does Gauss's law imply that the net electrostatic force from all the other ions is zero when the ion is displaced from equilibrium?

Comment: Whatever direction the Na ion is displaced, there must be an inward force. Hence there is an inward flux on any closed surface. From Gauss, there must be a negative charge inside, which there is not.

Answer (score 4):

Your argument with Gauss' law is incorrect, but a correct treatment can lead to a similar contradiction.

From central symmetry, the other ions apply a net zero force on the ion when it is in its site. This does not contradict the fact that there is a restoring force, since a restoring force vanishes at equilibrium. You'll need to look at its behaviour at a slight displacement from equilibrium.

However, for small displacement, the force is not zero (no matter how you apply Gauss' law). To check whether you have a restoring force, you'll need to do linear stability analysis, ie expand the electric field $E$ up to linear order. Since the electric charge is zero, Gauss law says that:
$$
\nabla\cdot E = 0
$$
If the equilibrium were stable at linear order, then $\nabla\cdot E <0$, since it is not the case, you cannot conclude on the stability of the equilibrium at linear order. This is a general fact, known as Earnshaw’s theorem. Thus, you indeed do not have a linear restoring force. In fact, in your case due to symmetry considerations, the force is zero up to linear order. You'll therefore need to go at higher order, but from the usual linear approach for phonons, you'd expect a linear restoring force.

To get this linear restoring force, you'll need to invoque quantum mechanics. The usual explanation for metals is that when the atoms are displaced this adiabatically modifies the conducting electrons. When treated as a gas, these electrons have a compressibility due to the Pauli exclusion principle leading to a restoring force. Quantitatively, this gives the Bohm Staver formula. This formula shows that the expression of the speed of sound (a proxy for the restoring force of the lattice) is fundamentally quantum (proportional to the Fermi velocity). I suspect that you'd get similar arguments for ionic solids.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I understand that the conduction electrons in the crystal can be viewed as a compressible gas, Could you explain physically how this picture explains the restoring force?

Comment: Bruus’ *Many Body Quantum Theory in Condensed Matter Physics* has a nice intuitive explanation in section 3.2 (electron phonon interaction and the sound velocity). In general, check out the derivation of the Bohm Starker formula.

Comment: I found online something called the Bohm-Staver formula, which gives the propagation speed of disturbances in the electron gas. How does that tell you that there is a restoring force on the ion?

Comment: Sorry my bad, fixed the name (can't edit the comment though). The fact that there is a sound velocity comes from the fact there is a local linear restoring force like d'Alembert's equation. Check out Bruus (available online), the equations are written out explicitly.

Comment: No prpblem about the name of the equation. I don't have access to the book, but I saw a derivation online that is clear. In any case, this shows that there is a restoring force for a density perturbation within the electron gas. How does this demonstrate the existence of a restoring force acting on a displaced ion?

Comment: I just saw your remark that the Bruus text is online, and I found it. There is a good discussion of quantized lattice vibrations. Maybe my original question, regarding the restoring force on a single ion, has no answer, since the vibrations are a collective phenomenon. After all, Bruus himself writes, at the start of 3.3, "the surroundings somehow supply the restoring force."

Answer (score 1):

The situation inside a crystal like that, where each nucleus has several electron orbitals, and several neighbours atoms, can not be simple.

But to have an idea of nucleus oscillation around an equilibrium point, it can be found in Griffiths book on QM, in the chapter analysing the Hydrogen molecule ion (2 protons and 1 electron). It is full QM and takes 4 pages to get a graph potential energy x distance between the protons, showing that there is a minimum around $2.4$ Bohr radius.

As the force is minus the gradient of the potential, its magnitude can be evaluated from the tangent to the curve, and it is a restoring force indeed.